# Docker doesn't cache npm install

Tags: node.js, caching, docker, npm

I can't seem to make my dockerfile cache my npm install. I have it set up like all the examples specify, and the package.json doesn't change but it still downloads all the dependencies.

Here's what I have

```
FROM mf/nodebox

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER Raif Harik <reharik@gmail.com>

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

ADD /app/package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install && npm install -g babel
RUN cd /tmp && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/app/current/node_modules

# Entrypoint to docker shell
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-shell"]

#this is the flag that tells the docker-shell what mode to execute
# Startup commands
CMD ["-r"]

# set WORKDIR
WORKDIR /opt/app/current

# Add shell script for starting container
ADD ./docker-shell.sh /usr/bin/docker-shell
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-shell

COPY /app /opt/app/current
```

Then the output I get is

```
Building domain...
Step 0 : FROM mf/nodebox
 ---> 4ee7c51a410d
Step 1 : MAINTAINER Raif Harik <reharik@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78d0db67240c
Step 2 : RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d7d360d8f89a
Step 3 : ADD /app/package.json /tmp/package.json
 ---> 5b373dae5141
Removing intermediate container f037272f49c3
Step 4 : RUN cd /tmp && npm install && npm install -g babel
 ---> Running in cb89bb6fc2d0
npm WARN package.json MF_Domain@0.0.1 No description
```

So it's caching the first couple commands, but it stops at Step 3 the ADD package.json and then goes to npm for Step 4.

**Edit:**

I guess i should mention that when I deploy a new change in the code ( or for my experimenting with this issue, just the same code ), while the package.json stays the same it is copies over to the deploy folder.  I don't know if docker checks the createddate, the checksum, or does a diff. If it's the createddate then maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache) it is said that

> In the case of the `ADD` and `COPY` instructions, the contents of the file(s) being put into the image are examined. Specifically, a checksum is done of the file(s) and then that checksum is used during the cache lookup. If anything has changed in the file(s), **including its metadata**, then the cache is invalidated.

Those *metadata* include the file modification time.

There are tricks to get around this (for instance [docker add cache when git checkout same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531108/docker-add-cache-when-git-checkout-same-file/26612694#26612694)).

See also the [related discussion](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4351) on the Docker github project.