# When does Docker image cache invalidation occur?

Tags: docker

Maybe my Google Foo is not strong enough, but I can't find a definite list about when Docker images in the cache are invalidated. Specifically, I'm interested at least in these scenarios:

- Invalidation because of **[mtime changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26612694/371137) vs [checksum changes](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/880#issuecomment-47076896)**. Which applies when? Can it deal with different source paths (e.g. clones of the repository in different directories)?
- Invalidation because of **updated base images**. At which point will (security) updates of e.g. Debian bubble down to me?
- Are there any **explicit APIs** that a continuous integration tool can use to tell Docker which cached images can be reused and which can't (for example because of a `wget foo.com/latest.gz`)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of Docker 1.8, Docker no longer uses `mtime` to invalidate the cache (this changed in this pull request [#12031](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12031)).

When building an image;

- For local content (`ADD myfiles /somewhere` / `COPY myfiles /somewhere`), docker uses checksum changes to invalidate the cache
- Remote content (`ADD http://example.com/foobar /somewhere`), is *always* downloaded, but the build-cache is invalidated based on checksum changes
- `RUN` instructions (such as `wget foo.com/latest.gz`) will never invalidate the cache, unless the instruction is changed; i.e., the cache is based on the text in the instruction. If you want reproducible builds, make sure these URLs point to a specific version (`wget http://example.com/package-major.minor.patch.gz`)

Docker 1.9 introduced support for [build-time arguments](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15182), which enable you to pass variables that can be used inside the Dockerfile so that you don't have to edit the Dockerfile to break the cache, or install a different version of the package.

For example

```
FROM foobar
ARG MAJOR=1
ARG MINOR=0
ARG PATCH=0
ADD http://example.com/package-$MAJOR.$MINOR.$PATCH.gz /
```

Will add http://example.com/package-1.0.0.gz by default, however, passing a "major", "minor" or "patch" build-time parameter can override the version to download, and will invalidate the cache;

```
docker build --build-arg MINOR=2 .                                           Sat Jan 16 13:22:40 2016
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 1c9b046c2850
Step 2 : ARG MAJOR=1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a149d88772ba
Step 3 : ARG MINOR=0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e3dae0189ffd
Step 4 : ARG PATCH=0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 678d7ae33054
Step 5 : ADD http://example.com/package-$MAJOR.$MINOR.$PATCH.gz /
Get http://example.com/package-1.2.0.gz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: getsockopt: connection refused
```

For more information about the build-cache, read [the build-cache section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache) in the documentation.

> At which point will (security) updates of e.g. Debian bubble down to me?

Docker will *not* automatically download updated images, or update your images that are based on them. However, if you `docker pull yourbaseimage`, and a newer image is downloaded, then the build-cache for images based on that is invalidated, so the next build will *not* use the cache.

For *automated builds* on Docker hub, you can make sure that images are automatic rebuilt if the base-image is updated, see the [documentation on automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#repository-links)

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

About the @thaJeztah's answer, I've tried it. And the `--no-cache` does not only force the current stage to rebuild, but also forces any dependant stage to be completely rebuilt. And this is not what we want.

But there's a way to force an invalidation only to specific stages: Use a named `ARG` and do not use it in the `Dockerfile`. And pass it as a `--build-arg` to `docker build`.

This creates a "different layer" and therefore invalidates anything behind.

## Rationale

This is an excerpt of my final dockerfile with 4 stages:

- `repo-sources-base` => The base to download my libraries - don't rebuild
- `repo-sources` => My libraries - rebuild
- `base` => Ubuntu with my apache, php, etc. - don't rebuild
- `production` => The base with my project and my libraries that goes to the production server - rebuild

see here:

```
#===========================================================================#
# Stage `repo-sources-base`                                                 #
# -------------------------                                                 #
# This image installs git so we don't have to install git it each time we   #
# rebuild the repo-sources.                                                 #
#===========================================================================#    
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS repo-sources-base

# Install git.
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    :

# Scan the gitlab host key.
RUN \
    touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    :


#===========================================================================#
# Stage `repo-sources`                                                      #
# --------------------                                                      #
# This image contains the SSH private keys to make the clone of the         #
# source code from gitlab. This key is passed via ARG to avoid hardcoding   #
# it here inside.                                                           #
#===========================================================================#
FROM repo-sources-base AS repo-sources

# NOTE THIS ARG!!!!!!!
# Not used anywhere... just declared.
# But invalidates the docker build cache on purpose!
# See the answer text for explanation.
ARG INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP="0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000Z"

# Inspired here https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/    
# Add credentials.
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN \
    mkdir /root/.ssh && \
    echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    :

# Clone the needed repos.
RUN mkdir -p whatever-path/repos

WORKDIR /whatever-path/repos

RUN git clone --quiet git@gitlab.com:my-nice-account/my-nice-project-1.git
RUN git clone --quiet git@gitlab.com:my-nice-account/my-nice-project-2.git maybe_deploy_dir_2
RUN git clone --quiet git@gitlab.com:my-nice-account/my-nice-project-3.git
RUN git clone --quiet git@gitlab.com:my-nice-account/my-nice-project-4.git


#===========================================================================#
# Stage `base`                                                              #
# ------------                                                              #
# This image contains the base operating system to build the production     #
# release on top of it. It is expected to mutate very slowly so we can have #
# the layers pre-cached when building.                                      #
# TODO: Separate this in 2 bases: one for production and the other for      #
#     development or testing, like in here:                                 #
#     https://www.docker.com/blog/advanced-dockerfiles-faster-builds-and-smaller-images-using-buildkit-and-multistage-builds/ #
#===========================================================================#
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS base

# Install apache, php, yarn or whatever "base production server"
# BUT NOT your source code, just "the base"


#===========================================================================#
# Stage `release`                                                           #
# ---------------                                                           #
# This image will be the one released to pre or prod and configured at      #
# runtime via env-vars like backing-services, databases, etc.               #
#===========================================================================#
FROM base AS release

# Copy the project files
COPY . /whatever-maybe-other-path/repos/app

# Copy the dependency files
COPY --from=repo-sources /whatever-path/repos /whatever-maybe-other-path/repos

# Continue with the "fine-tuning" after copying the source code, like static building, etc.
```

The 4 targets here are grouped in blocks of 2:

- `repo-sources-base` and `repo-sources` are meant for the local downloads having SSH keys that never get either deployed not locked into an intermediate layer that goes to production.
- `base` and `production` build the image to go to production.

The problem is what @Perseids said: Running the `docker build` just ignores the cloning of our repos as it's cached, and passing `--no-cache` rebuilds too much.

With this 4-target structure we build "once" `repo-sources-base` and `base` and we only want to rebuild `repo-sources` and `production`.

The key here is the `ARG` named `INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP`.

Here's the behaviour:

- If you rebuild `--target repo-sources` many times, it's loading from cache and we don't want that.
- If you rebuild `--target repo-sources --no-cache` it's forcing to also rebuilding the `repo-sources-base` and we don't want that.
- If you rebuild `--target repo-sources --build-arg X=Y` it's forcing to rebuild only if X is referenced in the `Dockerfile` and it has a "new value" even if it's not used later. This is why I "name" `INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP` in the `ARG` line.

So doing

```
docker build --target repo-sources --build-arg INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP=first [...]
```

Will build it.

Doing "again" this

```
docker build --target repo-sources --build-arg INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP=first [...]
```

uses the cache.

Changing the value like this

```
docker build --target repo-sources --build-arg INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP=second [...]
```

forces a rebuild

Now using `first` or `second` would use the cache but a new value would force a rebuild.

So what I do in my build script:

```
NOW=$(date --utc --iso-8601='ns' | sed 's/,/./' | cut -c 1-26 | sed 's/$/Z/')
docker build --target repo-sources --build-arg INVALIDATE_CACHE_TIMESTAMP=${NOW} [...]
docker build --target production [...]
```

So it "forces" the `repo-sources` to be built again and therefore the target `production`will take `base` from cache and `repo-sources` from the latest cached build that I enforced to rebuild.